# Unable to display Drush cache-clear theme registry

Tags: 7, drush

I was using drush to do some of the most frequently used Drupal tasks, mainly to cache clear. It was working great, but recently I'm getting only the following option:

```
Enter a number to choose which cache to clear.
 [0]  :  Cancel   
 [1]  :  drush    
 [2]  :  registry
```

It was supposed to be:

```
 [0]   :  Cancel         
 [1]   :  all            
 [2]   :  drush          
 [3]   :  theme-registry 
 [4]   :  menu           
 [5]   :  css-js         
 [6]   :  block          
 [7]   :  module-list    
 [8]   :  theme-list     
 [9]   :  nodeaccess     
 [10]  :  registry       
 [11]  :  token          
 [12]  :  views
```

There is no way to clear css/js or theme registry. Whats the problem? Is it with Drush or Machine settings. Any advise highly appretiated.

Comment: start with error reporting it may tell you something more 'drush watchdog-list', if you run 'drush cc all' , you get any errors?

Comment: @PanChrono: thanks for the reply. when I say, drush cache-clear all, it clears drush cache alone. no errors

Comment: @pown: can u check whether `$bind-address` mentioned anywhere in `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`?

Comment: @Ram: yes. That is pointed to my ip address.

Comment: @pown: Check my answer below.hope that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The Drush code looks like this:

  `$types = drush_cache_clear_types(drush_has_boostrapped(DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_FULL));`

If the parameter to drush_cache_clear_types is TRUE, then the missing cache types shown above are included in your selection list.  Your Drupal site is not bootstrapping all the way up to the 'FULL' level, which means there's probably something wrong with the Drupal site.  Try running `drush status --debug`, and see if you can determine from the log messages why the bootstrap is stopping.

**Update:** See MPD's comment below. I thought the exact same thing as I was driving in to work this morning: this situation can also arise if you have told Drush where your Drupal root is, but have not specified your sites folder.  The Drupal root is specified via --root, or by using cd to switch to a directory anywhere in your Drupal installation.  The specific site is selected via --uri, or by using cd to switch to the same directory that contains settings.php.  If you cd to the folder that contains settings.php and run `drush cc all`, that might fix your problem.

Comment: Just seeing "drush" and "registry" can be as simple as needing to specify a site when you aren't using sites/default.

Comment: when I run `drush status --debug` the only error I can find is `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`. But I'm using other websites running in the same machine without any trouble with Drush.

Answer (score 1):

I had this. I was using aegir. You would be in the wrong directory if you only see:

```
Enter a number to choose which cache to clear.
 [0]  :  Cancel   
 [1]  :  drush    
 [2]  :  registry
```

By going into `/var/aegir/platforms/xxx/sites/domainname/` and then running drush cache-clear you will get

```
[0]   :  Cancel         
 [1]   :  all            
 [2]   :  drush          
 [3]   :  theme-registry 
 [4]   :  menu           
 [5]   :  css-js         
 [6]   :  block          
 [7]   :  module-list    
 [8]   :  theme-list     
 [9]   :  nodeaccess     
 [10]  :  registry       
 [11]  :  token          
 [12]  :  views
```

Answer (score 0):

Bindaddress requires you to login remotely, so in settings.php you should change the host to the bind address.

Also you cant use root with empty password, instead Login to mysql

```
mysql -u root
```

create user and grand all permission and use that user in your settings.php

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO myname@'192.168.1.90' IDENTIFIED BY 'myname';

$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'project_db',
      'username' => 'myname',
      'password' => 'myname',
            'host' => '192.168.1.10',// if that is your ip
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```